# Styling Google Maps API to look like Google Maps on Mac

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

### Brief Explanation

I had not noticed this until my designer sent me a PSD of a new website including a Google Maps page with some cool features that I did not recognise...

I then investigated this further to try to find these features and where they came from. Surprisingly, the new features are only visible when you go to the Google maps page on a Mac (I was using Chrome).

See these two different screen shots:

**On a Mac**
[image: New features on mac]

**On a PC (Google Maps API)**
[image: Google Maps API]

### The Differences

1. There is a button after the search box
2. The Mac version has integrated Google Plus and sharing capabilities
3. The zoom buttons are entirely different
4. The map type buttons are entirely different

### My Question

So with the above in mind, is there any possible way one could make the Google Maps API Map look like the one illustrated in the first image?

I have looked through the API reference and it seems that there is nothing other than a basic search box... I cannot find any information on adding 'sharing' capabilities, or restyling the zoom buttons etc.

Can one come up with an some ingenious solution to this as the design of my clients site rather depends on the features on this map?

Comment: I think the Mac is using the new version of Google Maps and the PC the old version. It would just be a matter of choosing the new map version on the PC and then they should match.

Comment: @Andy You are correct to a certain extent. I have managed to get the Google maps on my pc to now use the newer version. But how do I get the API to use the newer version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're being served the updated version on the Mac and the older version on the PC; The user will need to opt-in to the new service on the Google Maps site to overcome this.

If you need more control over the design of your maps then Mapbox might be useful: https://www.mapbox.com